# Converting strings in an array to words in a 2d array

Tags: java

I have a program that displays lyrics on screen. Each line of lyrics is stored in an array. Now from this, I want to create a 2d array with just the individuals words organized in lines like this:

```
String[] lyrics = {"Line number one", "Line number two"};
String[][] words = {{"Line","number","one"},{"Line", "number", "two"}};
```

I thought it would just be a simple double for loop that just takes current string, gets rid of spaces, and stores words in array. When I try  this however, I get a type mismatch.

```java
public static void createWordArray() {
        for(int i=0; i<=lyrics.length; i++) {
            for(int j =0; j<=lyrics[i].length(); i++) {
                words[i][j] = lyrics[i].split("\\s+");
            }
        }
```

Comment: A 2d String array might not be the best solution if there are a different number of words per line: each element in the array must have the same length. Consider a List<List<String>> where each inner element is a word and each outer element is a list of words on a line.

Comment: The result of `split` is an array itself, so it would even be simpler than double for loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner for loop is not required.

```
public class CreateWordArray {
    static String[]  lyrics = {"Line number one", "Line number two"}; 
    static String[][] words = new String[lyrics.length][];

    public static void createWordArray() {
        for(int i=0; i<lyrics.length; i++) {
                words[i] = lyrics[i].split("\\s+");
        }
    }

   public static void main(String[] s) {

       createWordArray();
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(words));

   }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example solution using Streams.

```
public class WordArrayUsingStreams {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lyrics = {"Line number one", "Line number two"};

        String[][] words = Arrays.stream(lyrics)
              .map(x -> x.split("\\s+"))
              .toArray(String[][]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(words));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
[[Line, number, one], [Line, number, two]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use List , which is much dynamic and easy to control.

```
    String[] lyrics = {"Line number one", "Line number two"};

    //Create a List that will hold the final result
    List<List<String>> wordsList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    //Convert the array of String into List
    List<String> lyricsList = Arrays.asList(lyrics);

    //Loop over the converted array
    for(String s : lyricsList )
    {
        //Split your string
        //convert it to a list
        //add the list into the final result
        wordsList.add(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")));
    }

        //System.out.println(wordsList.toString());
```